# Can security camera run on router without internet?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, camera

Hello I've got a Amiccom wifi security camera that will not bind to my Belkin N300 router. I do not have internet access on the router. I got the router used just for this purpose, but can't get it to work. The software I'm using is Jawa. I can connect to the router with my phone, but when all the same login data is used to get the camera binded with the router, it won't.

Comment: I should mention that the camera will bind to my phone easily using mobile hotspot and I can access all features, but I need it hooked to my router (without internet) so it's constantly connected. I've tried a Linksys G and Belkin n300 routers, both reset, she won't work. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If the camera will save its recording (if it has already been set up) and if you can attach the camera to a device to collect the recording, then it does not need internet. Check this very carefully.

You might wish to give the camera a static IP if you can do this. A static IP will prevent the phone from grabbing the same IP, presenting a problem for the camera.

Otherwise (a) reset the router to work with your camera (use different login information) or (b) try a different router.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the Jawa software requires the camera to be connected to the internet. It won't work without it, at least for the initial setup.

After the camera is configured to store its images/video on the on-board SD card it can continue operation without being able to connect to the internet, but the phone app to communicate with the camera always requires an internet connection (on both the phone and the camera).

The phone doesn't connect to the camera directly. The Jawa servers on the internet always have to act as an intermediary.
This is simple to use for non-technical users: Just plug the stuff in to your local network and it just works.
It also let's you use the app from anywhere in the world and you can see what is going on in view of the camera.
But it makes the camera of limited use without an internet connection.